# Instagram API. Как уместиться в лимит 5000 запросов в час?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

В настоящее время в стадии разработки находится сайт http://webstagram.ru/, использующий Instagram API. Проблема в том, что даже на начальном этапе мы не попадаем в лимит 5000 запросов в час, от чего сайт перестает работать. Что можно сделать, чтобы снять этот лимит или же ограничить количество запросов?

Comment: Скажите, удалось связаться с инстаграмом для увеличения лимитов?

Comment: Каким образом это отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: @VladD такие ответы нужно сразу в комменты переводить :) А то еще и наминусуют человека, а жалко. Вроде как просто интересовался.

Comment: @lampa: угу, и то верно, новичкам надо помогать :)

Answer (score 7):

Судя по скорости работы сайта вы перенаправляете все запросы непосредственно к API. Это совершенно ни к чему.

Кэшируйте ответы API на некоторое время (подбирается/расчитывается из потребностей). Особенно имеет смысл кэшировать ответы на наиболее частые запросы.

Например "популярное" можно кэшировать на 15 минут, "рейтинги" можно смело кэшировать на несколько часов, а "фото дня" на сутки.

При этом можно мониторить кол-во запросов, и в случае недобора (не выбрали еще все 5000 запрсов в час) делать дополнительные запросы к API для актуализации информации в кэше и обновления популярных страниц.

Тем не менее, рано или поздно, вы все равно упретесь в лимит. Подумайте об использовании нескольких ключей или договаривайтесь об увеличении лимитов с instagram.